# Angularjs: what is the best way to define a constant?

Tags: angularjs

It is possible that I can define a constant in angularjs like this:
JS Code

```
app.controller('testController', function($scope) {
    $scope.TEST_CONST= {
        ASC: 1,
        DESC: 2
    };

    $scope.doSomething = function() {
       // using constant
       if ($scope.TEST_CONST.ASC) {
          // do something
       }
    }
});
```

HTML code:

```
// using in a template
<p ng-if="TEST_CONST.ASC">abc<p>
```

As you can see, in the js code, when I use the constant, the writting of constant definition is not concise, because I must add a **$scope** before the constant. It's much better if I just write *TEST_CONST.ASC* like in the template file. 
Is there any better way to define a constant?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need `$scope` to make your variable visible in the template. So there is no way to avoid using it. On the other hand, AngularJS has a special, more convenient, syntax for that purpose:

```
  angular
    .module('my.module')
    .constant('TEST_CONST', {
      ASC: 1,
    });
```

But still, you will need to inject it into the controller:

```
app.controller('testController', function($scope, TEST_CONST) {}
```

And then make visible in a template:

```
$scope.TEST_CONST = TEST_CONST;
```

Comment: How do I access the constant in js? Do I still write **$scope.TEST_CONST** ?

Comment: $scope is required to make your constants visible in the template, but, if you need `TEST_CONST` only in your controller there is no need to put it in the `$scope`